# Android - Cannot resolve Symbol 'FirebaseMessagingService'

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to connect Firebase Messaging to my Android app and I created a class that extends `FirebaseMessagingService` and it keeps saying

```
Cannot resolve Symbol 'FirebaseMessagingService'
```

I added this to the project level gradle:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'
```

App level gradle:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.0.0'
```

And outside of the app level gradle `dependencies tag`

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

My `Android Manifest` also has the following service

```
<service android:name=".fcm.SEFirebaseInstanceIDService">
    <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
    </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Pretty sure I followed the documentation to the tee. Why am I having this issue?

Comment: Did you press the button "Refresh all gradle projects" in Android Studio? This Button is in the gradle tab on the right side (two circular arrows). If this does not help execute the "dependencies" task (this task is located in the help folder) and upload the output as file.

Comment: The refresh all gradle projects didn't work. Can you give me more info on the dependencies task? Not sure how to get to that. Also, my project is still able to run even though that entire file is basically red and unable to find the imports. Is that normal?

Comment: What do you mean with "didn't work"? Can you add the output of the build tab (its located at the bottom border) after you press "Refresh all gradle projects"

Comment: What happens if you switch to: 
`classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0"`
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.1"`
`implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:12.0.1"`
BTW you should switch from `compile` to `implementation` for every dependency.

Comment: @user1185087 it just started working without doing anything but removing the app level gradle entries... compiling.. and adding them back

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have disabled offline mode

```
Settings - build and deployment - gradle - uncheck offline mode
```

Click apply, okay and Then sync again

Also make sure the Google gms plugin is at the bottom of your app level gradle file, after the dependencies closing brace.

Comment: Where is settings?

Comment: Use the shortcut Ctrl + alt + s

Comment: Okay, top left of Android studio, click file, you should see settings in the list there.

Comment: Ensure your project actually synced and firebase was downloaded.

Comment: You can try moving to an activity that isn't flagged as error and try typing Fireb... And see if Firebase suggestions popup if they do then just click build on the toolbar and select clean. Else confirm you have a working connection and sync again